# SublimeText 2 on Mac OS X: Build does not do anything, no errors

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I am trying to Run/Build a simple python file like:

```
def test(a):
    print a

test('blaat')
```

Running it from the commandline obviously runs fine. Trying it from within SublimeText nothing happens. I don't get build output, nor any errors in the console or in the OS's Console.app.

My `Python.sublime-build` for example looks like:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

But it does not matter if I change the command to `"cmd": ["randombullshit"],`. Nothing happens and no errors show.

The same goes for other languages such as coffeescript.

Any idea where to look? or what to change?

Comment: Have you tried watching the Console while you start the application for error messages, or seeing if it has a log for the program?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is saved before you attempt to build it, and go to `Tools -> Build System` and select `Python` instead of `Automatic`, just to be sure. You can see build results via `Tools -> Build Results`.

What might be happening is your preferences might be set to not automatically show build results. Go to `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings - User` and put in the following:

```json
"show_panel_on_build": true
```

If you don't have any personalized settings yet, the file should look like this:

```json
{
    "show_panel_on_build": true
}
```

This should (hopefully) fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't see it till now. The problem was fixed with an update of SublimeText